# MySQL - default value for TIMESTAMP(3)

Tags: mysql

My database is MySql 5.6.

I want to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value an attribute which is type of TIMESTAMP(3).

But I get the error:

> ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'updated'

I think it is because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is only in precision of second.

How can I set current time as the default value for a `timestamp` with fractional part?

Comment: Try first by not having 3 in TIMESTAMP(3). Also make sure that you only have one field in the table which is using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As per documentation on `timestamp` and `datetime` type columns:

> *If a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column definition includes an explicit fractional seconds precision value anywhere, the same value must be used throughout the column definition.*
>
> This is permitted:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>   ts TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
> );
> ```

**Other Examples**:

```
mysql> create table tbl_so_q23671222_1( ts timestamp(3) default now() );
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'ts'

mysql> create table tbl_so_q23671222_1( ts timestamp(3) default now(3) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.59 sec)

mysql> create table tbl_so_q23671222_2( ts timestamp(3) default current_timestamp );
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'ts'

mysql> create table tbl_so_q23671222_2( ts timestamp(3) default current_timestamp(3) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> desc tbl_so_q23671222_1;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| ts    | timestamp(3) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc tbl_so_q23671222_2;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| ts    | timestamp(3) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Refer to**:
[***Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)