# Invalid default value for 'last_modified'

Tags: mysql, timestamp, ddl

**MySQL Distrib 5.5**

**OS: Ubuntu 14.04**

I tried to import a database sql script into MySQL using this command:

```
mysql -u root databaseName < databaseName.sql
```

While creating a BD and loading a dump I am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 5: Invalid default value for 'last_modified'
```

**42000**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vote`.`user` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `last_modified` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `validation_code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_idx` (`username` ASC),
  INDEX `first_last_name_idx` (`first_name` ASC, `last_name` ASC),
  INDEX `last_first_name_idx` (`last_name` ASC, `first_name` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `phone_idx` (`phone` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Do you have any idea what caused this error? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Reduce the problem to the minimal testcase: remove lines from databaseName.sql until you isolate the problem.

Comment: Could you please show the result of `select current_timestamp();`?

Comment: this question has the same error message but suggests using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (which you already do) - could it be related to SQL modes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312144/error-error-1067-invalid-default-value-for-on-update-current-timestamp

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - default value for TIMESTAMP(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671222/mysql-default-value-for-timestamp3)

Comment: finaly able to fix the issue, seems like  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not acceptable with DATETIME field, i had to change it to TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `TIMESTAMP` data type in a column with a default timestamp.

```
`last_modified` DATETIME  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  /*wrong*/

`last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  /*right*/
```