# Is there any difference between TIMESTAMP(3) & TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Is there any difference between TIMESTAMP(3) & TIMESTAMP 
I am generating liquibase from mysql & while creating it throws an error

```
<column defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" name="createdate" type="TIMESTAMP(3)">
Invalid default value for 'createdate' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE
```

But it works I use TIMESTAMP

---

Problem is that when data is persisted in DB with TIMESTAMP like 2018-03-15 06:49:06 but when I create a table with TIMESTAMP(3) data persist like  2018-01-03 07:54:56.867
 Last millisecond value I need

Comment: TIMESTAMP(3) also stores the milliseconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - default value for TIMESTAMP(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671222/mysql-default-value-for-timestamp3)

Answer (score 3):

As per mysql doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

By default, timestamp does not contain milliseconds field
Ex: "2020-11-06 13:46:33"

But timestamp(3) stores milliseconds as well with precision as added in brackets (max 6).
Ex: "2020-10-19 13:27:05.912"